# How to Add users to pgAdmin docker deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, gitlab-ci, pgadmin

I'm currently running pgAdmin as a docker deployment to connect to our postgres RDS instance. The problem is, I redeploy this pgAdmin server fairly often, which means user accounts have to be recreated often. Does anyone know how I can script the creation of these ~5 user accounts so I can include it as a step in my CI pipeline? Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem can be solved by bash script within docker. Then you write bash script in a file named docker-entrypoint.sh and add these lines to your Dockerfile

```
ADD . /usr/src/app 
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

here is an example of same

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

# ENV IN_DOCKER=1

# Adding files
ADD . /usr/src/app

#CMD exec /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 manage.py migrate                  # Apply database migrations
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm more interested in if there's a pgadmin cli that can be used to add the users. I can't seem to find an answer out there.